# Fullcalendar and timezones

Tags: jquery, timezone, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar 1.5.3 and JQuery 1.7.2 - in my local timezone the data is displayed perfectly but in other timezones it works intermittently I assume due to the time difference relative to the local time in the time zone.

I am taking a JSON feed from a file and the dates are stored in MySQL as Y-m-d.

I have read up on ignoreTimezone and have set it to false and true in both fullcalendar.js and in the call on the page to the calendar object but it is making no difference. The documentation for ignoreTimezone mentions working on an ISO8601 date which mine is not.

In the below specific example a client in the US West Coast sees Christmas day showing as the 24th December - I have got confirmation from the client that they have used multiple browsers and machines and I have had this problem with more than one client so it sounds like it is not localised to one client machine etc.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    ignoreTimezone: false,
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',
        week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
        day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',
        week: 'ddd d/M',
        day: 'dddd d/M'
    },
    timeFormat: { // for event elements
        '': 'H(:mm)t' // default
    },      
    eventSources: [
    'public_holidays_feed.php'
]
})
});
</script>
```

A snip of my JSON feed shows:

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"New Year's Day (USA)","start":"2012-01-02","end":"2012-01-02","backgroundColor":"#000000","allDay":true},
{"id":"2","title":"New Year's Day (UK)","start":"2012-01-02","end":"2012-01-02","backgroundColor":"#000000","allDay":true},
{"id":"3","title":"Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr. (USA)","start":"2012-01-16","end":"2012-01-16","backgroundColor":"#000000","allDay":true},
{"id":"4","title":"Washington's Birthday (USA)","start":"2012-02-20","end":"2012-02-20","backgroundColor":"#000000","allDay":true},
{"id":"5","title":"Good Friday (UK)","start":"2012-04-06","end":"2012-04-06","backgroundColor":"#000000","allDay":true}
]
```

How can I get the above to ignore the local timezone and only use the server timezone so if the date in MySQL says 2012-12-25 then that is what everyone should see regardless of where they are?

Thanks

Comment: What is your server timezone?

Comment: hmm, maybe you want `ignoreTimezone: true` which  is default.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had a lot of problem with this issues,
please make sure you json feed is full:

ie:

```
[{"id":"190","allDay":false,"editable":true,"title":"Sam Shift","start":"2013-07-14 18:00:00","end":"2013-07-15 02:00:00"}]
```

I know that in docs "allDay" is default to false, but if it isnt full day please mark it,
and of course mark the start time and end time.

If your event is full day, make sure you mark it.

Hope it will work.

** of course place the date and time as you want, there is no connection to timezone, each client will see the event in the date string you sent.